# manipulate data of a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a CSV file containing about 30m rows with a column that has a date type. But the problem is with its format. PSQL supports '-' delimiters for timestamp but my dates are using '/'. For example, the date should be '2021-02-01 00:00:00' but my date format is '2021/02/01 00:00:00'. Also, I can not open the CSV file and change it manually due to its large size. I am trying to import my data into a temporary table to replace the '/' with '-' and then inserting them to a new table and I am using the following command(it is not the real table and it is just an example):

```
CREATE TABLE TMP(
    dt VARCHAR 
)

CREATE TABLE other_tmp(
    dt TIMESTAMP
)

INSERT INTO TMP VALUES('2020/01/02 22:33:11');

INSERT INTO other_tmp(dt)
SELECT dt, 
REPLACE(dt, '/', '-')
FROM TMP
```

I get an error with replace function when I want to run it.
Does anybody know that how can I solve this problem? Or even is it possible to manipulate the column in the original table?

Comment: Your `select` returns two columns but you are inserting into one column.  I consider this a typo.

Comment: You are wrong about the formatting: `select '2021/02/01 00:00:00'::timestamp; 2021-02-01 00:00:00`. As others have pointed out the issue is trying to squeeze two columns into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,
In this case, your column "dt" is of type timestamp without time zone but the expression is of type text. So the text should cast to timestamp as below.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TMP
(
    dt VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS other_tmp
(
    dt TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO TMP
VALUES ('2020/01/02 22:33:11'::TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO other_tmp(dt)
SELECT REPLACE(dt, '/', '-')::TIMESTAMP AS dt
FROM TMP;
```

Comment: I tried it but it throws an error and gives this hint:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Comment: @MasoudAkbari Updated, yes you need to cast it to TIMESTAMP

Comment: This answer is misleading and over complicated. The important part is that `'2020/01/02 22:33:11'` is a perfectly valid format for a timestamp. In either case above all you have to do is `INSERT INTO TMP VALUES('2020/01/02 22:33:11');`

Answer (score 1):

Your first error is that you have two columns in the SELECT list, but only one column in the INSERT target.

To convert a string to a timestamp, use `to_timstamp()`

```
insert into other_tmp(dt)
select to_timestamp(dt, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
from tmp;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=485c81a787413b7e64acd44cf6679d65)